# Proving a result related to Legendre polynomials

Tags: calculus, legendre-polynomials

Prove $$J= \int _{-1}^1 xP_nP_{n-1}dx=\frac {2n}{4n^2-1}$$ where $P_n $ is the Legendre polynomial of degree n . $$\text {**My attempt**} $$ Using  by parts assuming $u=x,v=P_nP_{n-1} $ the first part vanishes and we get $$\int _{-1}^1 (\int (P_nP_{n-1} ) $$ now I dont know how to handle this indefinite integral even if I substitute Rodrigue's formula. Another thought was using generating function but that too didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the recursion formula
$$(n+1) P_{n+1}(x) = (2n+1) x P_n(x) - n P_{n-1}(x)$$
Rearrange and multiply with $P_{n-1}(x)$
$$(2n+1) x P_n(x)P_{n-1}(x) = (n+1) P_{n+1}(x)P_{n-1}(x) + n P_{n-1}(x)P_{n-1}(x)$$
Then integrate
$$(2n+1)\int_{-1}^{1} x P_n(x)P_{n-1}(x)dx = \int_{-1}^{1}(n+1) P_{n+1}(x)P_{n-1}(x)dx + \int_{-1}^{1}n P_{n-1}(x)P_{n-1}(x)dx$$
and use the orthogonal property on the RHS
$$(2n+1)\int_{-1}^{1} x P_n(x)P_{n-1}(x) dx = 0 + n \frac{2}{2(n-1)+1}$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1} x P_n(x)P_{n-1}(x) dx =  n \frac{2}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$$
and finally get the result

> $$\int_{-1}^{1} x P_n(x)P_{n-1}(x)dx =  \frac{2n}{4n^2-1}$$

Comment: How did you get that recurrence relation?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: Bonnet's recursion formula, Rodrigues' formula and the generating function for Legendre polynomials can be proved to be equivalent statements. What is your definition of $P_n$?

Comment: @Jack D  Aurizio I thought it was a result . My definition is Rodrigue's formula.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: well, then you may just prove that the RHS and LHS of Bonnet's identity fulfill the same differential equation (Rodrigues formula).

Comment: So the one above is Bonnet's identity ?